# NullPointerException and app crashes when using .getInt (Android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I'm using an intent and getIntent on my Android app but it crashes in the emulator. Logcat indicates that my problem it's a NullPointerException but since yesterday I just can't find the solution for this problem.

Here is my Logcat:

```
10-05 20:27:12.053: E/AndroidRuntime(246): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
10-05 20:27:12.063: E/AndroidRuntime(246): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.Tonos/com.example.Tonos.TonosSet}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-05 20:27:12.063: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
10-05 20:27:12.063: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
10-05 20:27:12.063: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
10-05 20:27:12.063: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
10-05 20:27:12.063: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-05 20:27:12.063: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-05 20:27:12.063: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
10-05 20:27:12.063: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-05 20:27:12.063: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-05 20:27:12.063: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
10-05 20:27:12.063: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
10-05 20:27:12.063: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-05 20:27:12.063: E/AndroidRuntime(246): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-05 20:27:12.063: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at com.example.Tonos.TonosSet.onCreate(TonosSet.java:21)
10-05 20:27:12.063: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-05 20:27:12.063: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
10-05 20:27:12.063: E/AndroidRuntime(246):  ... 11 more
```

This is my "TonosSet.java":

```
package com.example.Tonos;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class TonosSet extends Activity {
/**
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(Bundle)
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.tonos_set);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view2);
    TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.namesong);
    TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.artist);

    switch (position){
    case 0:        
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pico);

        textView1.setText("Tone1");
        textView2.setText("Someone");        
    break;

    case 1:        
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pict);

        textView1.setText("Tone2");
        textView2.setText("Someone");           
    break;

    }


}
}
```

And here is the part of code that creates the Intent "i" (Tonos.java):

```
....            
maListViewPerso.setAdapter(mSchedule);

    maListViewPerso.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id){
                HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) maListViewPerso.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Toast.makeText(Tonos.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent tonosset = new Intent(Tonos.this, TonosSet.class);
                startActivity(tonosset);

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TonosSet.class);

                i.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(i);

            }


    });

}
}
```

Thanks a lot guys! =)

Comment: As @Cyril already said you start twice and with the first one empty. But be sure that you always check that your extras not be null before doing something else; try with something like this:
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
 position =extras.getInt("id");
}

Comment: Also, you should read the docs on putExtra, esp. regarding the package prefix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 // First time you start TonosSet activity (without extra)
 // If you want to start TonosSet activity only once, comment two following line
 Intent tonosset = new Intent(Tonos.this, TonosSet.class);
 startActivity(tonosset);

 // Second time you start TonosSet activity (with extra this time)
 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TonosSet.class);
 i.putExtra("id", position);
 startActivity(i);
```

You start TonosSet activity twice. First time you launch it, the intent doesn't have extra. To resolve your problem check your intent have extra.

```
Intent i = getIntent();
int position = -1; // init with default value
if(i.getExtras() != null)
    position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
```

Comment: blah! Got a phone call in the middle of typing my answer and you beat me to it!

Comment: I hope it was important phone call to break your answer :)

Comment: Important, perhaps, but not entirely urgent...I ended up half-listening while I finished typing my last sentence.

Comment: I've changed my getIntent as you told me but when I'm in the emulator (in TonosSet Activity)  and press back it shows me TonosSet Activity again but whit out the text and image of the strings.xml and @drawable instead of go back to the Tonos activity =( Sorry, I'm doing my first app.

Comment: It's totally normal. First you start TonosSet without extra. Next you start second TonosSet with extra. The second activity is displayed and you get position from extra and display your ui (depending of position equal `0` or `1`. When you press back you back to the first tonosSet activity without extra. The problem is you can't get position from the extra, so position have the default value: -1, and in your switch you have case `0` and `1`. Solution is to add default case in your switch that display special ui when position is unavailable

Comment: I've add a default case in my switch but I dont want to put another ui when position is equal to -1, I would like to go back to Tonos Activity, How I can do that?

Comment: Start TonosSet activity only once. Remove the first start `Intent tonosset = new Intent(Tonos.this, TonosSet.class);` `sartActivity(tonosset);`. Check edited answer for more details.

Comment: =D Thanks a lot!! Now my app run as I want!! thanks! Thanks!!! As I told you, I'm learning and i've learnig a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
            Intent tonosset = new Intent(Tonos.this, TonosSet.class); 
            startActivity(tonosset); 

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TonosSet.class); 

            i.putExtra("id", position); 
            startActivity(i);
```

You are creating two intents: one has an extra and the other doesn't. The NPE occurs when you try to get an extra from the activity that doesn't have one.

Comment: Upvote for the phone call you got! You made me laugh big time :)